# Read maxAttempts of spring @Retryable from application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

```
@Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttempts = 3)
public Boolean sendMessageService(Request request){
   ...
}
```

maxAttempts argument in `@Retryable` annotation is hard coded. Can i read that value from `application.properties` file?

something like

```
@Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttempts = "${MAX_ATTEMPTS}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can by using maxAttemptsExpression:

@Retryable(value = {Exception.class},
        maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${maxAttempts}}")

Add @EnableRetry above your class if you have not already done so.

Comment: no need of this #{}. direct "${}" itself will work.

Answer (score 1):

No; it's not possible to set via a property when using the annotation.

You can wire up the `RetryOperationsInterceptor` bean manually and apply it to your method using Spring AOP...

**EDIT**

```
<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
    <property name="retryOperations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="${max.attempts}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="${delay}" />
                    <property name="multiplier" value="${multiplier}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="retries"
        expression="execution(* org..EchoService.test(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retries" advice-ref="retryAdvice"
        order="-1" />
</aop:config>
```

Where `EchoService.test` is the method you want to apply retries to.