# How can I make spring @retryable configurable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I have this piece of code

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, stateful = true, include = ServiceUnavailableException.class,
        exclude = URISyntaxException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2) )
public void testThatService(String serviceAccountId)
        throws ServiceUnavailableException, URISyntaxException {
```

//some implementation here
}

Is there a way I can make the maxAttempts , delay and multiplier configurable using @Value? 
Or is there any other approach to make such fields inside annotations configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible; to wire in properties, the annotation would have to be changed to take String values and the annotation bean post-processor would have to resolve placeholders and/or SpEL expressions.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003086/read-maxattempts-of-spring-retryable-from-application-properties-file/38053043#38053043) for an alternative, but it can't currently be done via the annotation.

**EDIT**

```
<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
    <property name="retryOperations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="${max.attempts}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="${delay}" />
                    <property name="multiplier" value="${multiplier}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="retries"
        expression="execution(* org..EchoService.test(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retries" advice-ref="retryAdvice"
        order="-1" />
</aop:config>
```

Where `EchoService.test` is the method you want to apply retries to.

Comment: If you dont mind , could you provide an example as well using RetryOperationsInterceptor ?

Comment: I added an example using XML config.

Answer (score 30):

with the release of Spring-retry version 1.2, it's possible. @Retryable can be configured using SPEL.

```
@Retryable(
    value = { SomeException.class,AnotherException.class },
    maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@myBean.getMyProperties('retryCount')}",
    backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{@myBean.getMyProperties('retryInitalInterval')}"))
public void doJob(){
    //your code here
}
```

For more details refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 10):

If you want to supply a default, and then optionally override it in your application.properties file:

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${my.max.attempts:10}}")
public void myRetryableMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As it is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43144064

Version 1.2 introduces the ability to use expressions for certain properties.

So you need something like this:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, stateful = true, include = ServiceUnavailableException.class,
        exclude = URISyntaxException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${your.delay}}" , multiplier = 2) )
public void testThatService(String serviceAccountId)
        throws ServiceUnavailableException, URISyntaxException {
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but at least for me it works without `#{}`. I.e, `"${your.delay}"` is picked up (of course, you need to define it in your properties file first).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RetryTemplate` bean instead of `@Retryable` annotation like this:

```
@Value("${retry.max-attempts}")
private int maxAttempts;
@Value("${retry.delay}")
private long delay;

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(delay);

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    return template;
}
```

And then use the `execute` method of this template:

```
@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

public ResponseVo doSomething(final Object data) {
    RetryCallback<ResponseVo, SomeException> retryCallback = new RetryCallback<ResponseVo, SomeException>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseVo doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws SomeException {
             // do the business
             return responseVo;
        }
    };
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryCallback);
}
```