# How to inject config properties in Spring Boot to Spring Retry annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

In spring boot application, I define some config properties in yaml file as below.

```
my.app.maxAttempts = 10
my.app.backOffDelay = 500L
```

And an example bean

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.app")
public class ConfigProperties {
  private int maxAttempts;
  private long backOffDelay;

  public int getMaxAttempts() {
    return maxAttempts;
  }

  public void setMaxAttempts(int maxAttempts) {
    this.maxAttempts = maxAttempts;
  }

  public void setBackOffDelay(long backOffDelay) {
    this.backOffDelay = backOffDelay;
  }

  public long getBackOffDelay() {
    return backOffDelay;
  }
```

How can I inject the values of `my.app.maxAttempts` and `my.app.backOffdelay` to Spring Retry annotation? In the example below, I want to replace the value `10` of maxAttempts and `500L`of backoff value with the corresponding references of config properties.

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=10, include=TimeoutException.class, backoff=@Backoff(value = 500L))
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Staring from [spring-retry-1.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) we can use configurable properties in @Retryable annotation.

Use "maxAttemptsExpression", Refer the below code for usage,

```
 @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${my.app.maxAttempts}}",
 backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${my.app. backOffDelay}}"))
```

It will not work if you use any version less than 1.2.0.Also you don't require any configurable property classes.

Comment: Is there any way to have the properties in yaml file only, meaning without adding the @Retryable annotation? In other words, are there any yaml config properties for the above?

Comment: I get a `After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'` running this

Comment: I am getting the same error - there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'

Answer (score 13):

You can also use existing beans in expression attributes.

```
    @Retryable(include = RuntimeException.class,
           maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@retryProperties.getMaxAttempts()}",
           backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{@retryProperties.getBackOffInitialInterval()}",
                              maxDelayExpression = "#{@retryProperties.getBackOffMaxInterval" + "()}",
                              multiplierExpression = "#{@retryProperties.getBackOffIntervalMultiplier()}"))
    String perform();

    @Recover
    String recover(RuntimeException exception);
```

where

> retryProperties

is your bean which holds retry related properties as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring EL as shown below to load the properties:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts="${my.app.maxAttempts}", 
  include=TimeoutException.class, 
  backoff=@Backoff(value ="${my.app.backOffDelay}"))
```

Comment: Strange that you had a few upvotes, for me it fails with a `Error:(21, 27) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int`. Seems that the EL expression is not being evaluated.