# Spring boot 2.0 - configuration for users

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I have an application (springboot 2) where customer would like to edit integer value, which represents value for maximum of AutoGrowCollectionLimit. This value is by default (according to spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html)) set to 256 and this is not enough for our purposes.

The code, where the property is set:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit([configurable_number]);
}
```

This value should be configurable in configuration file (lets say some.txt), which will be delivered as a txt file next to an application. It doesn't matter now where will be some.txt file placed, even root for an application is ok for now.

This mean, that as a customer I am able to change it easy. Open some.txt file and change the value from i.e.: 256 to i.e.: 555.

During investigation I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143806/how-to-inject-config-properties-in-spring-boot-to-spring-retry-annotation). But its not suitable for my case. What I am searching for is configuration in some.txt file with really simple property i.e.:

AutoGrowCollectionLimit=[configurable_number]

According to spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), I tried following:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(${set.max.collectionLimit});
}
```

And also edited [projectUrl]/src/main/resources/application.yml with following:

```
set:
    max:
     collectionLimit: 500
```

IDE is expecting ')' or '}', when I am trying to call this property in:

```
binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(${set.max.collectionLimit});
```

Can someone help?

Comment: That is as far from a proper question as it gets. You should start by writing some code.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, it is better right now?

Comment: It's much better, yes. While you're waiting for the question to reopen, take a look at the [Spring Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) documentation, specifically the information around providing additional .yml or .properties files outside of your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to create externalized configurations in Spring Boot, but you need to use `@Value` injection to achieve pretty much all of them.

#### Value Injection

To inject your configuration values, you need to use the `@Value` annotation. This can be done in all the same places that you can use `@Autowired`. For example, on a property:

```
@Value("${com.example.app.host-name}")
private String hostName;
```

Or via a constructor or method:

```
@Value("${com.example.app.host-name}")
public void setHostName(String hostName) { ... }
```

Or on a specific constructor or method parameter:

```
public MyServiceBean(
        @Value("${com.example.app.host-name}") String hostName,
        @Value("${com.example.app.port}") int port) {
    ...
}
```

You can also supply defaults using this system using a `:` symbol, e.g.:

```
@Value("${com.example.app.port:8180}")
public void setPort(int port) { ... }
```

The `${}` bit in all of these is interpreted using the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions). In this case, the `${property}` syntax tells Spring to retrieve the value of `property` from the context, which is done by looking up the property in all the [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) beans in the context. You can do this yourself as well using [`Environment.getProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) via the context, e.g.:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = ... ;
int port = appCtx.getEnvironment().getProperty("com.example.app.port", Integer.class);
```

It's just more convenient to use `@Value` annotations for the same reason it's more convenient to use `@Autowired`

#### Spring Boot Configuration

Since you're using Spring Boot, you already have some `PropertySource` instances in your app. For example, your `application.yml` file is loaded as a `PropertySource`. Note that Spring will translate a property named `a.b.c` to nested documents in your YAML file. In your case, this would be `set.max.collectionLimit`.

Spring Boot does this by looking for `application.yml` and `application.properties` files, as well as other sources of properties like [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), and the default order for how Spring Boot looks for these properties can be found [here in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

#### External Configuration

To externalize your configuration, you state that you don't want to use .yml files, but what about .properties? E.g.:

```
set.max.collectionLimit=555
```

You would place this file alongside your .jar file and name it `application.properties`. Any values in this file would override the values you have in your internal `application.yml` file.

They could also [override it directly on the command line](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args), e.g.:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --set.max.collectionLimit=555
```

Or via `System` properties:

```
java -Dset.max.collectionLimit=555 -jar your-app.jar
```

All of these would be valid ways of overriding the value, but only if you use value injection, e.g. via `@Value`.