# How to use property from a property file in the `@Backoff` annotation for customize delay time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

How to use property from a property file in the `@Backoff` annotation for customize delay time?
This attribute takes only a constant as a value.
I try to initialize `someProperty` field with constructor injection, but it not helps and IntellijIDEA shows a message: "Attribute value must be a constant".

This code won't compile:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final long someProperty;

    public SomeClass (@Value("${someProperty}") Long someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    @Retryable(value = RuntimeException.class, maxAttempts = 2, 
               backoff = @Backoff(delay = someProperty))
    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

Can I use `delayExpression` attribute like this:

```
@Retryable(value = RuntimeException.class, maxAttempts = 2, 
           backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${someProperty}"))
```

Comment: You cannot create an annotation that is modified at runtime.  Annotation metadata is set at compile time only.

Comment: It seems that the question already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143806/how-to-inject-config-properties-in-spring-boot-to-spring-retry-annotation