# Can I use a Spring @Value variable from properties in another annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I currently have a variable coming from a property file, declared as:

```
    @Value("${retryLimit}")
    private int retryLimit;
```

That I would like to use in an annotation instead of the hard-coded constant "3" in this case:

```
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
```

Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = @Value("${retryLimit}"), backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
```

However I get the following compile error:

```
"Incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value', required: 'int'"
```

Comment: Annotation parameters must be compile-time constant expressions.

Comment: Pease have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088449/how-can-i-make-spring-retryable-configurable)

Comment: see [How to inject config properties in Spring Boot to Spring Retry annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43143806/217324)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `@value` inside another annotation tag. Just use with out `@value`. It will work.

```java
@Retryable(maxAttempts = "${retryLimit}", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
```